# Support for Form Post response mode?

Tags: google-oauth, openid-connect

Does Google plan to support the Form Post response mode in its OpenID Connect/OAuth 2.0 implementation?

http://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html

Other identity providers such as [Azure Active Directory](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/09/09/openid-connect-and-oauth-2-0-support-in-azure-active-directory-has-ga-d.aspx) and [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) support this, but it seems Google doesn't (based on reading the docs and some manual testing). For context, I'm building an OpenID Connect library and was hoping to leverage this capability (and prefer not to rely on acquiring tokens via HTTP GET and URL fragments).

Comment: Any news from Google on this subject? I have exactly the same question. Google Identity Platform is "openid certified" so I was expecting it to support form_post response mode, but I just discovered that it is not the case...

Answer (score 2):

This does appear to work when you pass `?response_mode=form_post` to google... but I can't find it anywhere in their documentation. :shrug:

Comment: I appreciate the answer, even if nearly 6 years later! :D  If I can get confirmation that this works (either through my own testing or from someone else) then I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: It seems to work for me, too. Is apparently an undocumented feature.